# Meaning of 'what is this compared to her previous song'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage, sentence-meaning, esl

'What is this compared to her previous song'.

Two people argued about whether a song was good or not, and one just responded with this.

What did they mean by that? I haven't found any satisfactory explanation yet, please help.

Comment: *Two people argued* - Were they both native English speakers? What was said before this?

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: Compare the dismissive "Who is he?" = "He's not worth considering."

Comment: Is that countable sense of "people" as meaning "person" correct? "Two persons argued…"